# If an eventual inequality holds for $f$ and $g \sim f$ then does it hold for $g$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose $f$, $g$, are non-negative functions such that $f \sim g$ (meaning that $f(x)/g(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$). If for all $\lambda > 1$  there exists an $\eta > 0$ such that $$f(\lambda x) - f(x) > \eta x\tag{1}$$ for all $x$ sufficiently large, is the same true of $g$?

I think it is. Here's what I've tried: let $\lambda > 0$ and let $1 > \varepsilon > 0$, to be chosen later. Get $\eta, x_0 > 0$ so that $f(\lambda x) - f(x) > \eta x$ for all $x \ge x_0$. Let $x_1$ be such that $$1 - \varepsilon < \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} < 1 + \varepsilon$$ for all $x \ge x_1$. Then for $x \ge \max\{x_0, x_1\}$ we have 
$$g(\lambda x) - g(x) > f(\lambda x)(1-\varepsilon) - f(x)(1+\varepsilon) = [f(\lambda x) - f(x)] - \varepsilon f(\lambda x) - \varepsilon f(x).$$
The bracketed term is bounded below by $\eta x$, 
and, on multiplying (1) through by $\varepsilon$ we can bound the last term below by $\varepsilon\eta x - \varepsilon f(\lambda x)$. Putting it all together, we get 
$$g(\lambda x) - g(x) > \eta(1-\varepsilon) x - 2\varepsilon f(\lambda x).\tag{2}$$
But this bound is too low. I understand I can get away with just a small multiple of $\eta$ as the coefficient on $x$; the trouble is, I don't know if $f(\lambda x)$ is dominated by some $\alpha x$ for $\alpha < 1$. So maybe there is a different approach?

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of such an $f$? Preferrably, of course with the inequality being satisfied, uhm, rather sharp.

Comment: Take $f(x) = x$ with $\eta = \frac{1}{2}(\lambda - 1)$.

Comment: Ah, I was under the wrong impression that $\eta$ does not depend on $\lambda$. But your question aims at showing that, if the assumption is true for $f$ for one $\lambda, \eta$ pair, it is true for $g$ with the same pair?

Comment: Not quite: my goal is to show that $g$ has the same *property*: that for each $\lambda > 1$ there exists an $\eta$ (not necessarily the one that works for $f$) which makes (1) hold for $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof doesn't work because: counterexample.

Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be a non-decreasing sequence of non-negative reals.
Let $f,g\colon[1,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ be given by
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=x+a_{\lfloor\ln x\rfloor}\\
g(x)&=f(e^{\lfloor\ln x\rfloor})\end{align} $$
Then $f$ has the desired property because 
$$ f(\lambda x)-f(x)\ge (\lambda-1)x.$$
On the other hand, if $1<\lambda<e$ then there are arbitrarily large $x$ with $g(\lambda x)=g(x)$. Hence $g$ does *not* have the property.

Remains to adjust $a_n$ to achieve $f\sim g$.
Note that for $e^n\le x<e^{n+1}$ we have
$$g(x)=a_n+e^n\le f(x)<a_n+e^{n+1}=g(x)+(e-1)e^n$$
Hence it suffices to ensure that $\frac{(e-1)e^n}{a_n+e^n}\to 0$, so for example $a_n=e^{2n}$ will work.

Comment: Why does $g(\lambda x) = g(x)$ for arbitrarily large $x$? (Also, note that I did not claim my proof worked - I just wanted to show my attempt!)

Comment: Ah! Because we can make $x$ run through the values $e^n$ with $n \to \infty$! Great counterexample!

Answer (score 0):

As Hagen von Eitzen's counterexample shows, the claim is false. However, it *can* be salvaged if we assume the *stronger* asymptotic relation: $$g(x) = f(x) + o(x).\tag{*}$$
Assuming $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \ne 0$ 
then (*) implies $g \sim f$, since
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)-f(x)}{\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)} + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1.$$
Hagen's counterexample does *not* satisfy (*), since 
$$\frac{g(x) - f(x)}{x} = \frac{e^{\lfloor\log x\rfloor} - x}{x} = e^{-\{\log x\}} - 1\tag{^}$$
where $\{\xi\} \in [0, 1)$ 
denotes the fractional part of the real number $\xi$.
The limit of (^) does not exist as $x \to \infty$, because $e^{-\{\log x\}}$ oscillates too much.

To prove that (*) implies (1), write $g(x) = f(x) + r(x)$ where $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{r(x)}{x} = 0$.
Let $\lambda > 0$ and get $\eta$ and $x_0$ such that $f(\lambda x) - f(x) > \eta x$ for all $x > x_0$.
Then $$g(\lambda x) - g(x) = [f(\lambda x) - f(x)] + [r(\lambda x) - r(x)] > \eta x + x\left[\lambda \frac{r(\lambda x)}{\lambda x} - \frac{r(x)}{x}\right].\tag{3}$$
Now for $\varepsilon > 0$ to be chosen later, let $x_1$ be such that $|r(x)/x| < \varepsilon$ for all $x > x_1$. Since $\lambda > 1$, we have $\lambda x > x > x_1$, so $|r(\lambda x)/\lambda x| < \varepsilon$ also. 
Thus we can bound below the bracketed term in (3): 
$$\left[\lambda \frac{r(\lambda x)}{\lambda x} - \frac{r(x)}{x}\right] > -\lambda\varepsilon - \varepsilon = -\varepsilon(\lambda + 1).$$
Hence, for $x > \max\{x_0, x_1\}$, 
$$g(\lambda x) - g(x) > (\eta - \varepsilon(\lambda + 1))x.$$
We want the coefficient on $x$ to be positive, 
so we complete the proof by taking $\varepsilon < \eta/(\lambda + 1)$.

Comment: For the record, to have $g(x) = f(x) + o(x)$ imply $f \sim g$ it is enough to assume that $1/f(x)$ is bounded, which is to say $\liminf f(x) > 0$.